# deploy lambda function using cloud9 and IAM identity center

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, cloud9-ide

I am a beginner with AWS so forgive me if the question is not clear.

I am trying to deploy a lambda function from cloud9.

I have initiated the default `hello world` python lambda function.

```
AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_03228be2e7e9a0f4:~/environment/lambda-python3.7 $ ls
events  hello_world  __init__.py  README.md  README.TOOLKIT.md  template.yaml  tests
AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_03228be2e7e9a0f4:~/environment/lambda-python3.7 $
```

I am an admin so I should have all permissions:

```
AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_03228be2e7e9a0f4:~/environment/lambda-python3.7 $ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "050672679339", 
    "UserId": "AROAQXTCTXGVTFSKEJKUV:luca.puggini", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::050672679339:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_03228be2e7e9a0f4/luca.puggini"
}
AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_03228be2e7e9a0f4:~/environment/lambda-python3.7 $ ls
```

When I try to deploy I get some permission errors:

```
AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_03228be2e7e9a0f4:~/environment/lambda-python3.7 $ sam deploy --stack-name pikeen-example-interface --resolve-s3 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM

                Managed S3 bucket: aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-1izrwnq0e6foe
                A different default S3 bucket can be set in samconfig.toml
                Or by specifying --s3-bucket explicitly.
File with same data already exists at a3735344f55aa1d5670127b3f2557a91, skipping upload

        Deploying with following values
        ===============================
        Stack name                   : pikeen-example-interface
        Region                       : eu-central-1
        Confirm changeset            : False
        Disable rollback             : False
        Deployment s3 bucket         : aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-1izrwnq0e6foe
        Capabilities                 : ["CAPABILITY_IAM"]
        Parameter overrides          : {}
        Signing Profiles             : {}

Initiating deployment
=====================
File with same data already exists at 584381adaf4b34cfa8377c0a8e92b097.template, skipping upload

Waiting for changeset to be created..
CloudFormation stack changeset
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation                                                                                 LogicalResourceId                                                                         ResourceType                                                                              Replacement                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Add                                                                                     HelloWorldFunctionHelloWorldPermissionProd                                                AWS::Lambda::Permission                                                                   N/A                                                                                     
+ Add                                                                                     HelloWorldFunctionRole                                                                    AWS::IAM::Role                                                                            N/A                                                                                     
+ Add                                                                                     HelloWorldFunction                                                                        AWS::Lambda::Function                                                                     N/A                                                                                     
+ Add                                                                                     ServerlessRestApiDeployment47fc2d5f9d                                                     AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment                                                               N/A                                                                                     
+ Add                                                                                     ServerlessRestApiProdStage                                                                AWS::ApiGateway::Stage                                                                    N/A                                                                                     
+ Add                                                                                     ServerlessRestApi                                                                         AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi                                                                  N/A                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Changeset created successfully. arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:050672679339:changeSet/samcli-deploy1686176258/7c9bdf59-94fc-4a54-9501-891507319407


2023-06-07 22:17:44 - Waiting for stack create/update to complete

CloudFormation events from stack operations (refresh every 0.5 seconds)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceStatus                                                                            ResourceType                                                                              LogicalResourceId                                                                         ResourceStatusReason                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                                                                        AWS::IAM::Role                                                                            HelloWorldFunctionRole                                                                    -                                                                                       
CREATE_FAILED                                                                             AWS::IAM::Role                                                                            HelloWorldFunctionRole                                                                    The security token included in the request is invalid (Service:                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ID: 4e004f19-599a-4880-b496-c484df00925d; Proxy: null)                                  
ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS                                                                      AWS::CloudFormation::Stack                                                                pikeen-example-interface                                                                  The following resource(s) failed to create: [HelloWorldFunctionRole]. Rollback          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              requested by user.                                                                      
DELETE_COMPLETE                                                                           AWS::IAM::Role                                                                            HelloWorldFunctionRole                                                                    -                                                                                       
ROLLBACK_COMPLETE                                                                         AWS::CloudFormation::Stack                                                                pikeen-example-interface                                                                  -                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: pikeen-example-interface, Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_03228be2e7e9a0f4:~/environment/lambda-python3.7 $
```

How can I fix this? Thanks :-)